# Synchronizing two ListViews in WinRT

Tags: xaml, listview, gridview, synchronization, windows-runtime

I'm trying to synchronize the selected items of two different ListViews in a WinRT application, so that selecting an item(s) in one selects the same in the other.  Both lists are bound to the same data source.

I thought that you could use the IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem property of the ListView to manage synchronization, but this always seems to throw an exception when I try it ("Setting IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem to true is not supported"), and anyway is perhaps not intended for use with multiple selected items.

Is there a way to programmatically select items in a given ListView in WinRT? Or what is the correct way to keep the selected items on two lists synchronized?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the WinRT XAML Toolkit. It has a sample for ListViewExtensions in the samples app that seems to do almost exactly what you ask for.